CSS Grid automatically increases the width of items when there is available space remaining
I have questions regarding the provided snippet. I have a set of 5 cards, arranged in rows of 3 cards each, styled using grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, 1fr));. My query is: Is there a method wherein the 4th and 5th divs, representing the remaining two cards, can occupy the entire width of their respective row, dividing the remaining width equally between them? Furthermore, if only one card remains, should it occupy the full width of the row. I'm aware we can target them using nth-of-type, but what if I'm fetching the cards from an API? In that case, I won't know the specific div numbers representing the remaining 2 or 1 card.


body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
}
<body>
<div class = "card"></div>
<div class = "card"></div>
<div class = "card"></div>
<div class = "card"></div>
<div class = "card"></div>
</body>



Output should look like this:


No, that's a job for flexbox.

You want something like this?


body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




The solution works well, why the downvote? The OP didn't request a Flexbox solution, but Flexbox is way suited for this job.

Yes something like that. Is there a way to implement that utilizing grid? or my only option is using flexbox?

@DailyFun I think your only option is to use Flexbox.
